# IEEE Access moving the image to be at bottom of the page

Tags: ieeeaccess

I am using [IEEE Access template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/ieee-access-template) and I want to have my figure to be at the bottom of the page instead of the top, but using `hbp` the image goes to the last page of the document like so.

[image]

Here you have the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%% Todo list -- remove after
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand{\done}{\rlap{$\square$}{\raisebox{2pt}{\large\hspace{1pt}\cmark}}%
\hspace{-2.5pt}}
\newcommand{\wontfix}{\rlap{$\square$}{\large\hspace{1pt}\xmark}}
%%

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}


\tfootnote{This paragraph of the first footnote will contain support 
information, including sponsor and financial support acknowledgment. For 
example, ``This work was supported in part by the U.S. Department of 
Commerce under Grant BS123456.''}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}


\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Enter key words or phrases in alphabetical 
order, separated by commas. For a list of suggested keywords, send a blank 
e-mail to keywords@ieee.org or visit \underline
{http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani\_prod/keywrd98.txt}
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2-4]

\Figure[!htp](topskip=0pt, botskip=1pt, midskip=0pt)[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}{f1.\label{fig:f1}}
\lipsum[2-4]
\Figure[!htp](topskip=0pt, botskip=1pt, midskip=0pt)[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}{f1.\label{fig:f3}}

\Figure[!htp](topskip=0pt, botskip=1pt, midskip=0pt)[width=.65\textwidth]{example-image-duck}{f2.\label{fig:f2}}


\lipsum[1-10]

\EOD

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure how to add the `.cls` file in here, but the provided link should work.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. Why not use `[b]` option (b=bottom)? `[htp]` means, try `here`, then `top`, then `next page`.

Comment: Make the big image small enough to fit in the column.

Comment: Class file is at: https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/

Comment: Using [b] throws the image at the bottom of the document (last page of the document), meaning that all the images will be placed afterwards. I can't make it smaller as I want it to have that size (this is a dummy image). Anything that is not `[!htp]` makes the images go to the end of the document.

Comment: using htp explicitly prevents the figure going to the bottom so if you want it to go to the bottom you need to include b or better don't use the option at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Read the question again.  No `t`; it says `hbp`..

Comment: @barbarabeeton er it says `\Figure[!htp]`

Comment: @GuilhermeTheis -- Your question text doesn't agree with the code.  Near the top, the text says `hbp`, but in the code, near the bottom, there are three lines with `[!htp]`.  This is confusing, and a trap for people who read the text more carefully than the code.

Answer (score 2):

This solution loads `dblfloatfix` to allow bottom floats.  The big problem is that `twocolumn` floats have to be created on the previous page.

It wasn't clear in what order you wanted the captions to appear, so I assumed the worst case and used `\setcounter{figure}{...}` to manually set the caption numbers.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%% Todo list -- remove after
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand{\done}{\rlap{$\square$}{\raisebox{2pt}{\large\hspace{1pt}\cmark}}%
\hspace{-2.5pt}}
\newcommand{\wontfix}{\rlap{$\square$}{\large\hspace{1pt}\xmark}}
%%

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{graphicx} redundant
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}


\tfootnote{This paragraph of the first footnote will contain support 
information, including sponsor and financial support acknowledgment. For 
example, ``This work was supported in part by the U.S. Department of 
Commerce under Grant BS123456.''}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}


\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Enter key words or phrases in alphabetical 
order, separated by commas. For a list of suggested keywords, send a blank 
e-mail to keywords@ieee.org or visit \underline
{http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani\_prod/keywrd98.txt}
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2-4]

\Figure[!htp](topskip=0pt, botskip=1pt, midskip=0pt)[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}{f1.\label{fig:f1}}

\setcounter{figure}{2}% for figure 3
\Figure[b](topskip=0pt, botskip=1pt, midskip=0pt)[width=.65\textwidth]{example-image-duck}{f3.\label{fig:f3}}

\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{figure}{1}% for figure 2
\Figure[!htp](topskip=0pt, botskip=1pt, midskip=0pt)[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}{f2.\label{fig:f2}}
\setcounter{figure}{3}% resume automatic
\lipsum[1-10]

\EOD

\end{document}
```